# IllegalArgumentException and Illegal partition for 'val' in sqoop

Tags: sqoop, oozie, hue

I have asked this question over and over and am starting to believe that I am missing out on something really basic here. Not a lot of people seem to have come across this and I am really stuck on this one:

I get this error when I specify merge key argument with incremental import lastmodified in sqoop. If I run the job through command line, it works alright but not when I submit it to oozie. I submit my jobs through oozie. Not sure if oozie is the problem or hue, but sqoop job is not since it really works fine when executed through command line including the merge step.

My sqoop job looks like this:

```
   sqoop job --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://FQDN:16000/sqoop  
    --create test_table -- import --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --connect
     jdbc:mysql://IP/DB?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull --username 
     USER_NAME --password 'PASSWORD' --table test_table --merge-key id --
    split-by id --target-dir LOCATION --incremental lastmodified 
    --last-value 0 --check-column updated_at
```

The first import works alright .Starting second import I get:

I  created a small test table to test with an int, datetime and varchar , without any NULL or invalid chars in the data and yet I faced the same issue:

```
# id, updated_at, name
'1', '2016-07-02 17:16:53', 'l'
'3', '2016-06-29 14:12:53', 'f'
```

There were only 2 rows in the data and yet I got this:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.mergeParts(MapTask.java:1848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Error: java.io.IOException: Illegal partition for 3 (-2)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1083)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeMapperBase.processRecord(MergeMapperBase.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeTextMapper.map(MergeTextMapper.java:58)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeTextMapper.map(MergeTextMapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.mergeParts(MapTask.java:1848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Error: java.io.IOException: Illegal partition for 1 (-2)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1083)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeMapperBase.processRecord(MergeMapperBase.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeTextMapper.map(MergeTextMapper.java:58)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MergeTextMapper.map(MergeTextMapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

I get this error only in OOZIE and submit the job through HUE and this works just fine including the Merge mapreduce when I run the sqoop job through command line

Taken from oozie launcher, This is what my mapreduce job logs look like:

NOtice: MERGE map-reduce job failed error at the bottom:

> > > Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>

```
    5373 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
    5407 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.7.0
    5702 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
    5715 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
    5740 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory  - Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
    5754 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Using default fetchSize of 1000
    5754 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool  - Beginning code generation
    6091 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM test_table AS t WHERE 1=0
    6098 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM test_table AS t WHERE 1=0
    6118 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager  - HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
    8173 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager  - Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-yarn/compile/454902ac78d49b783a1f51b7bfe0a2be/test_table.jar
    8185 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM test_table AS t WHERE 1=0
    8192 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Incremental import based on column updated_at
    8192 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Lower bound value: '2016-07-02 17:13:24.0'
    8192 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Upper bound value: '2016-07-02 17:16:56.0'
    8194 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Beginning import of test_table
    8214 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM test_table AS t WHERE 1=0
    8230 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - SQOOP_HOME is unset. May not be able to find all job dependencies.
    8716 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat  - Using read commited transaction isolation
    8717 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat  - BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM test_table WHERE ( updated_at >= '2016-07-02 17:13:24.0' AND updated_at < '2016-07-02 17:16:56.0' )
    8721 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.IntegerSplitter  - Split size: 0; Num splits: 4 from: 1 to: 1
    25461 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Transferred 26 bytes in 17.2192 seconds (1.5099 bytes/sec)
    25471 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Retrieved 1 records.
    25536 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - IOException checking input file header: java.io.EOFException
    25550 [uber-SubtaskRunner] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - SQOOP_HOME is unset. May not be able to find all job dependencies.
    Heart beat
    Heart beat
    70628 [uber-SubtaskRunner] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Merge MapReduce job failed!
    70628 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Saving incremental import state to the metastore
    70831 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Updated data for job: test_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround that fixed it for me: http://www.yourtechchick.com/sqoop/illegal-partition-exception-sqoop-incremental-imports/